# How to call xml in Java servlet from JavaScript

Tags: java, xml, servlets

Hi I want to call my XML in java servlet from java script
This is my Servlert (Employee.java)
I want to get values from XML to java script

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    writer.append("<emp_description>");

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_addr,  FROM  employee");

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            writer.append("<employee>");
            writer.append("<emp_id>").append(resultSet.getString("emp_id")).append("</emp_id>");
            writer.append("<emp_name>").append(resultSet.getString("emp_name")).append("</emp_name>");
            writer.append("<emp_addr>").append(resultSet.getString("emp_addr")).append("</emp_addr>");
            writer.append("</employee>");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Handle.
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null)
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) { }
        if (statement != null)
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) { }
        if (connection != null)
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) { }
    }

    writer.append("</emp_description>");

}
```

I want to call this servlet from java script
Like this

```
<script>
 $.get("Employee", function(data) {
        //how can I Load values like
        Employename:
        EmployeeAddr:


});
 </script>
```

Please help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer:**

Your javascript (jQuery) has to look like this:

```
$.get("Employee", function(data) {
    var EmployeeName = $(data).find("emp_name").text();
    var EmployeeAddr = $(data).find("emp_addr").text();
});
```

**The longer answer:**

The above js code only works if there is only one employee in your xml. If there should be multiple employees in your xml you have to make some changes:

**1)** In your java code you query the database and save only the first row of the result as xml. If you want to have every employee in your xml you have to use a while loop:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    writer.append("<employee>");
    writer.append("<emp_id>").append(resultSet.getString("emp_id")).append("</emp_id>");
    writer.append("<emp_name>").append(resultSet.getString("emp_name")).append("</emp_name>");
    writer.append("<emp_addr>").append(resultSet.getString("emp_addr")).append("</emp_addr>");
    writer.append("</employee>");
}
```

**2)** Then you also have to use a for each loop in your javascript to get the name and address of each employee:

```
$.get("Employee", function(data) {
    $(data).find("employee").each(function(){
        var EmployeeName = $(this).find("emp_name").text();
        var EmployeeAddr = $(this).find("emp_addr").text();
    });
});
```